# Shuffling a meteor collection

Tags: javascript, arrays, collections, coffeescript, meteor

I'm building a card game and need to shuffle players' decks before the game starts. That is done with no issues by shuffling the array before inserting it to the database. However, after the game starts, there are some instances where players need to shuffle their decks. The only way came to my mind was to re-insert the deck after being shuffled again, but that is surely ineffective. 
here is the code for shuffling before inserting.

```
deck = _.shuffle (Card_Reference.find deck_id: hoster.deck).fetch()


    _.each deck, (card) ->
        Deck.insert
            userId: opponent._id
            game_id: id
            card: card.card
```

after inserting

```
deck = Deck.find().fetch()
ids = _.pluck deck, "_id"
shuffled = _.shuffle deck
Deck.remove {_id: $in: ids}

_.each shuffled, (card) ->
    Deck.insert
       userId: opponent._id
       game_id: id
       card: card.card
```

This is of course ineffective and unnecessary.
So, how would shuffling a collection be?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to have the same shuffle for all players or different shuffles for each player?

Comment: @AndrewMao what I want is when a player clicks shuffle button, the player's  deck is shuffled again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, removing and re-inserting is an inefficient way to shuffle, especially if rendering the cards is a time-consuming operation. I suggest the following method, which only generates `moved` operations if the `Deck` is being rendered in an `{{#each}}`, for example:

#### Wherever you use the deck that requires shuffling, use a cursor that sorts on a shuffle order:

```
deck = Deck.find({}, {sort: {order: 1}}).fetch()
```

#### Now, change the orders whenever you need to shuffle:

```
newOrder = _.shuffle [1..52] # or whatever Deck.find().count() is
Deck.find({}).forEach (card, idx) -> 
  Deck.update(card._id, $set: {order: newOrder[idx]})
```

This method of shuffling won't cause anything to remove and reappear in the collection. As long as you scope the find operations properly for the player and the game, so that other decks are unwittingly shuffled, you should be in business.

Comment: So, following this way, if I want to insert a card at the bottom of the deck, I just give it an order of the deck size +1, and negative values to add a card on the top of the deck, right?

Comment: Yes, but in that case you may want to do something smarter to keep track of the indices that are being used, because they won't be contiguous.